# How to allow other than @Test annotation to be executed via maven-surefire-plugin. I want @BeforeClass and @AfterSuite to be picked

Tags: java, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

In my Java code , I have below 3 methods .When I ran the pom.xml Run as Maven Install ,
only the @Test method get picked .

```
    @Parameters("year")
@Test (groups = {"smoke"})
public void newUserAuthenticationTest(String year){
    System.out.println("Sniff-"+year);
}
@Parameters("year")
@BeforeClass (groups = {"smoke"})
public void beforeMe(String year){
    System.out.println("Before -"+year);
}
@Parameters("year")
@AfterSuite (groups = {"smoke"})
public void afterMe(String year){
    System.out.println("After -"+year);
}
```

Is there a way to include annotations other than @Test when running via maven-surefire-plugin?

I wish to have @AfterSuite ,@BeforeClass

Here is my maven-surefire-plugin configuration .

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <year>2020</year>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
         <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>TestPlanLoc/FirstTestPlan.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Seems priority also not supported . @Test (priority=1,groups = {"smoke"}) throws an error ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project CiCdWebDriverJenkinsGitDocker: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved when changing the Execution environment to JDK , previously it was JRE.

[image]